# Maximum size for an unsupported bench

Tags: safety, lumber, strength

I intend to make a number of [simple wooden benches](http://www.mycarpentry.com/easy-bench-plans.html) in the near future.

[image: Simple Bench]

However, my aim is to make a wider bench capable of seating four across - pew style. Can I reliably assume that the same plan will work with a width of 80-96 inches? What kind of bowing might occur? Might they break?

Comment: Short answer; use the sagulator, which is technically for shelf spans but works well for estimating the load-bearing capacity of any horizontal wooden surface supported only at the ends with optional aprons. Also see http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/1388/49

Comment: If you need more strength, another board glued & screwed under the seat, to form a T or inverted L when seen from the end, , can add a great deal of strength.

Comment: if the feet are fixed to the floor, then this bench is WAY stronger than the sagulator would indicate.  since the vertical "back rest" member is acting as a "T" beam.  So I wouldn't vote it as duplicate at all.